# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u03b2'

Tags: python-3.6

I am using python 3.6 and writing/printing some statement. It works great locally, but when I run it on djnago I am getting following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u03b2' in position 6:
```

Its same file and same code. I checked the sys default setting on server and its utf8.

Its this line which is causing the issue

```
reportDoc.write( f"\t{begin_part}***{middle_part}***{end_part}\t({match_startIndex}-{match_endIndex})")
```

Comment: Can you post the code snippet that is causing that error? My initial reaction would be to make it a raw string by adding `r'text'` before the text but I can't know unless I see the code

Comment: updated the question